# Create new dataframe from two dataframes. One df contains column indices the other df the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have two dataframes of equal dimensions.

`df1` contains column indices.

```
    left   right   opp 
0    2       0      1
1    2       1      0
2    1       2      0
```

`df2` contains values of interest.

```
    value1   value2   value3
0    10      25         60
1    30      40         100
2    80      45         30
```

I want to create a dataframe that takes the column indices from `df1`, and uses them to grab the values from `df2`:

```
    left    right      opp
0    60      10         25
1    100     40         30
2    45      30         80
```

I was hoping to solve this with `applymap` and `iloc`. Something like this:

```
df3  = df1.applymap(lambda x, y: df2.iloc[x,y])
```

However, `applymap` only takes in the value of the cell, not the index and value.

I feel this should be a trivial operation, but I'm not seeing it at the moment. I couldn't find a duplicate question either. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not that hard but we need help from .values

```
df=df1.apply(lambda x :df2.values[x.index,x])
   left  right  opp
0    60     10   25
1   100     40   30
2    45     30   80
```

Comment: Similar but simpler approach than mine. `a=df2.values` and pass it to `lambda` would save some time :-)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of operations can be interpreted as numpy's indexing or pandas' `lookup`:

```
# numpy indexing
rows = np.repeat(df1.index.values,df1.shape[1]).reshape(df1.shape)

pd.DataFrame(df2.values[rows, df1], index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
```

Output:

```
   left  right  opp
0    60     10   25
1   100     40   30
2    45     30   80
```